# What does this WIFI sound mean?

Tags: wireless-networking, audio

**Main Problem:**

Slow downloading/streaming internet speed (Browsing: Perfect) , Wireless Card making sound after enabling it, not hardware sound, windows sound that when you enable it.

- 7mbps of internet speed according to speed test.
- Download stucks in the middle from every website.
- Video streaming stucks on every video website.
- Tried using different browser, doesn't solved the issue.
- Made changes in Google Chrome Flags doesn't solve the issue either.
- Disabled some windows services doesn't solve the issue.
  .

  ---

**WIFI Sound:**

can someone tell me what this sound means?

**Listen here:** http://vocaroo.com/i/s17BiQTobcoR

- First Sound: Wifi - Disabled (Sound).
- Second Sound: Wifi Re-Enabled (Single - Sound) and then a small like tapping twice sound (Twice and very low).

---

****Some Information Regarding my system ****

Intel Core 2 DUO T6500 2.10 GHz
4 GB RAM
64 bit operating system 
Windows 7 Ultimate
Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter

Have disabled couple of windows services to boost my computer speed. My IPV6 is also disabled at the moment.

It also makes this sound when I scan my computer for hardware changes and shows this.

[image]

---

**Update:**

- Updated my wireless card driver from 2009 to 2013.
- Disabled Bluetooth still the screen capture bluetooth icons show up.
- After enabling the Wireless Card it still makes that weird sound that I posted above.
- New Issue after restarting my PC after driver update which is digitally signed and the right driver the Wireless Card LED is constantly blinking.

Comment: Maybe you can describe the sound for those of us who can't listen at the moment. Is there a set number of beeps? Where is this sound coming from? Is the sound irregular - meaning does it sound unintentional as if pieces are grinding/moving in a way they shouldn't be?

Comment: @root It's a windows sound when you enable a wifi card. I have a switch on my laptop to enable or disable wifi. When I enable my wifi it makes an irregular windows sound at the end. It's like windows is indicating me that something is wrong with the card. Usually it doesn't make that sound when I enable my wifi card.

Edited: Just want to clear that it's not a hardware sound. It's by default windows sound but this time it makes different sound after enabling it at the end. It seems like an error sound.

Comment: Do you have the latest wifi drivers for (what I'm assuming is) your WNIC? It's worth checking to make sure the card is properly configured, some wireless interface cards have power save settings that hinder or completely terminate wireless use after X amount of minutes. The more details you provide about your system, when the problem occurs, what triggers you believe may play a role in the problem, the better.

Comment: what do you mean by WNIC? 
I have INTEL core 2 DUO T6500 2.10 GHZ 4 GB Ram, 64-bit operating system. Atheros Wireless Network. Windows 7 Ultimate.

I have disabled couple of windows services to boost my computer speed. and I also have IPV6 disabled, because i think its not required by my network.

Comment: WNIC = Wireless Network Interface Card. Consider checking the drivers for this device as mentioned.

Comment: @root alright im checking latest driver. Driver i'm using right now is from 2009. It's so hard to download a 2.4 mb driver -_-, I'm getting 7MBPS.

Comment: That screen capture is showing a bluetooth device/peripheral which is connecting to your computer using the laptop's bluetooth adapter. Try disabling the bluetooth receiver to see if it stops. Bluetooth does have a network layer and some devices use bluetooth for networking. Something which constantly hooks into and then drops out of the network could conceivably cause some problems for other devices which are relying on the network stack.

Comment: @horatio i have disabled the bluetooth device.
I just updated my driver from 2009 to 2013 to the latest one.

After restart this new thing came up, Wireless Card button on my laptop his LED light is constantly blinking now and the whenever i enable the device it makes the sound that i have posted.

Answer (score 1):

There are two sounds audible, both are two tones. One is a bee-boop, and the other is a boo-beep.

The "bee-boop" (first sound) indicates the discovery of a new device and the attempt to initialize it. That sound is heard any time a hot-pluggable device is added to the system or enabled. You will hear it if you, for example, connect a USB flash drive.

The "boo-beep" indicate the loss of a hot-pluggable device. You will hear that sound if you remove a USB flash drive.

As for explaining your issue, it seems that the computer tries to initialize the device and then the device disconnects. This could be caused by any number of things including a defective device, a defective port, an incorrect driver, or a port with insufficient power to run the device.

Comment: Does it have to do anything with the windows services that I have disabled. I checked online and made sure they are unnecessary. 

the driver that I have is official driver from my sony manufacturer's website.

Browsing is 100% perfect! speed is 7MBPS but every download gets stuck in the middle, every streaming stops in the middle. 

i might have to take it to a technician then I guess.

Comment: OK this is something new.

Now the wireless card LED is *blinking*, now what does this mean?

Comment: any clue someone?